# Django - Generating New Classes Automatically

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Is there a way for a user in localhost/admin to great a new class automatically, rather than by having to add the code manually?

For example, let's say I have an app the tracks the statistics of players on a baseball team, and have defined a class for the statistics of the players on the team. If I want the user to be able to create a new table to house statistics of players on a different team (with the exact same Fields as the previous team, is there a way for the user to do this in localhost/admin?

Comment: Why would you want to create a new table or class for that? Seems like very poor data modelling to have a different table per team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to think of models as representations of your database. You don't want to dynamically create tables in your database. It needs consistent structure for sanity's sake.

That said, what you are describing can be done with related models. For example, a structure like this will allow you to add as many teams as you'd like:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = ...
    # Whatever other attributes.

class Player(models.Model):
    first_name = ...
    last_name = ...
    # Assign players to a team.
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    # Whatever stats you want to keep on the players
```